# Multiprocessing performance for functions inside the code pipeline

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pool

So I am parallelizing a code pipeline where I am basically doing topic modelling of a large number of documents. The training part for tfidf calculation and other stuff is a seperate independent process.

For the output generation, this seems to me quite a parallel problem. Every document has to basically go through the same steps so in my opinion they can all run on seperate cores in seperate processes simultaneously.

I am using multiprocessing.Pool to create pools and then assign them the individual document. When I see the execution times of inside functions such as wordnet similarity calculation for different tokens, pos tagging of tokens and finding the position of titles in the documents etc, I see great time increase in the execution of all these functions. 
This increase in time for execution of these functions ultimately renders the multiprocessing to be a futile effort. Can someone please explain that is this a normal behaviour or should I look into it.

PS: Machine shows 36 cores. As I increase the number of pooled processes, the time in the functions also starts to increase. I create an instance of this class in my "run.py" script and call the main function to execute.
Here is my code:

```
class TitleGenerator:
    def main(self):


        """Loading necessary objects in parent process"""

        # Start generating titles
        if self.options.generate_titles:
            self.parallel_titles()

    def parallel_titles(self):
    """ Generates titles for all documents and writes to output file
    """
        # Files for writing the outputs
        with open(output_file, "w") as out:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
            csv_writer.writerow(column_names)

        # iterable target ids
        document_ids = list(document_ids) #around 200000 in number
        # document_ids is a list of lists where every inside list contains 200 entries i.e. we pass 200 documents to one worker in one go.        

        pool = mp.Pool(10)

        # mapping the job to pools
        pool.map(self.worker_func, document_ids)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def worker_func(self, doc_id):
    """ Worker function used through the multiprocessing pool to generate titles and write to output file

    Args:
        document_id : target_id for which titles are to be returned.
    """

        import spacy
        _nlp_model = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
        for target_id in doc_id:

            with open(filepath.review_tags_output, 'a') as out:
                csv_writer_res = csv.writer(out)
                # function that produces titles
                titles = self.generate_titles(doc_id, w2vmodel,tfidfmodel, _nlp_model) 

                # function that uses regex stuff to find the positions of titles in text and writes it to a csv file
                find_titles(target_id, titles, _nlp_model, csv_writer_res) 
                del titles
            gc.collect()


    def self.generate_titles(doc_id, word2vecmodel, tfidfmodel, _nlp_model):
    """ Get titles from the documents
    """

    def find_titles(doc_id, titles, dataframe , nlp_model, csv_writer=None):
   """ Finds the position of titles in document and writes the output.
   """
```

Comment: the func and parameters to `pool.map` are all `pickle`d when sending to the worker processes.  if these are big (as your models could well be) then this could be dominating total execution time…